# How do i calculate the derivative of Lagrange polynomial Li Function?

Tags: python, polynomials, derivative

Currently i'm stuck in finding the lagrange polynomial Li function's derivative. This is how i write the Li function :

```
def Li(x, xArr, n):
  L = 1
  resArr = []
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):        
      if j == i:          
        continue
      L = L * ((x - xArr[j])/ (xArr[i] - xArr[j]))
    resArr.append(round(L,4))
    L = 1
  return resArr
```

And i want to calculate the derivatives of the array results from the function. For example, if we try to hardcode it, with a given xArr = [10.5, 12] it will look like :

```
L[0] = (x - xArr[1]) / (xArr[0] - xArr[1]) * (x- xArr[0]) / (xArr[1] - xArr[0])
L[0] = (x - 12)/(10.5 - 12) * (x - 10.5)/(12 - 10.5)
L[0] = (x^2 - 22.5x + 126) / -2.25
```

and then we'll find the derivative of L[0] with that function *(x^2 - 22.5x + 126) / -2.25*, in manual solving, we can insert the x later, but if we code it, i assume that the code must know the x value first, right?

so, for example i give the x value = 11.5, and it makes the results of L[0] = 0.3333

and now i want to calculate the derivative of L[0] and the result will be :

```
L'[0] = 2x - 22.5 / -2.25 for x = 11.5
L'[0] = 0.5
```

Is there any ways to do so? I've tried using torch.tensor, and using np.diff, but the results is not satisfying. Thank you.

Comment: add more details to your question, explain what you are expecting etc...

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you want so more details per comment from @ombk would be helpful, but if you want a numerical derivative of your function you can do it like this. Note we use `numpy` for arithmetic operations on arrays as basic lists do not work like that

```
import numpy as np
eps = 0.1
L_base = Li(11.5, [10.5, 12], 2)
L_bumped = Li(11.5+eps, [10.5, 12], 2)
derivs = (np.array(L_bumped) - np.array(L_base))/eps
derivs
```

Here we bump `x` by a small amount, recalculate yourfunction and see the rate of change (which is the definition of first derivative)

The code produces

```
array([-0.666,  0.666])
```

these are (numerical) derivatives of `L[0]` and `L[1]` with respect to `x` at `x=11.5`

A few comments. Why do you do `round(L,4)` in your code? It is nice for printing out the results but does not work for numerical calculations as you lose precision. especially with derivatives, setting `eps` to `1e-4` in the code above does not work because the result gets rounded off

Also your 'by hand' example is wrong, and inconsistent with your code. For `xArr` of two elements, 'Li' functions are linear so it should be

```
L[0] = (x - xArr[1]) / (xArr[0] - xArr[1]) 
L[1] = (x- xArr[0]) / (xArr[1] - xArr[0])
```

finally you do not need `n` as one of the function arguments as you can just calculate it from the list xArr, `n=len(xArr)`